# How do I make one button as default in angular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-material

I have some group of buttons in angular material code, so I want to make the first button as default, where it shows the content of that button on right side.

[image: wishlists button]

I have written some code like below, it shows the result after I clicked the button.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between">
    <div class="list" style="width:30%;height:50px">
        <div layout="column" ng-repeat="lists in vm.result | filter:searchText">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around">
                <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="vm.showItems(lists._id)">{{lists.wName}}'s Wish List {{$index}}</md-button>
                    <a style="margin-top:14px; cursor:pointer">{{lists.wType}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="listItems" style="width:68%;height:400px;">
        <div flex-xs flex-gt-xs="30" layout="row" ng-show="vm.showOnClick">
            <md-card ng-repeat="product in vm.result" flex="30" style="max-width: 50%;">
                <md-card-title>
                    <md-card-title-text>
                        <span class="md-subhead">{{product.Product_Name}}</span>
                     </md-card-title-text>
                </md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-media style="margin-left: -80px;">
                    <img ng-src="{{ product.Image }}" class="md-card-image" alt="Image here">
                </md-card-title-media>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Price: </span>  {{ product.Price }}</span><br/>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Brand:</span>  {{ product.Brand }}</span><br/>
                    <span><span class="md-subhead" style="font-weight: bold; padding:2px;">Category: </span>  {{ product.Category }}</span><br/>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I didnt understand what you are trying to achive.

Comment: when page loaded the first button has to be triggered and content of that button has to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is to have the first item selected as default when your page is displayed. To do this, your controller should run the showItems method for the first item in the list once they have loaded.

I don't know what your controller or service looks like, but it would be something like (in your controller)

```
itemsService.loadItems().then(function(items) {
    showItems(items[0]);
});
```